# HTML / CSS layout problem with Stack Overflow flair

Tags: support, design, flair

I have my flair (`<script>` snippet) on my webpage and I would like to have an image or a text right next to it.

Like this: [flair] [my object]

The only way I've managed to handle it so far is like this:
[flair]
[my object] or the other way around.

I've tried adding "display: inline" and "float: left / right" to both the elements (both separately and also to both at the same time). Which in my case are the `<script>` and a `<h1>`.
After thinking about these for a while I came to conclusion that the script tag doesn't really work as normal HTML tag but more like a shortcut to longer code, so whatever CSS styles I add to it will be added to nothing.

Is there any other way than using table? I've been told tables aren't supposed to be used as layout so I guess it would be a lazy workaround to give up and go for the table.

Comment: Sounds like an SO question...

Comment: Hehe, ok. I just thought to put it here because SO is asking me "is your question about programming?" haven't really considered HTML / CSS programming. Because flair is SO related I thought this would be the place. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS-Positioning. If float isn't working, try some relative and absolute positions.